# Angularjs includes an empty option in select

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have a dropdownlist with data being bound dynamically this way at Page_Load:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSet" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="PKSetId" runat="server" 
AppendDataBoundItems="true" ng-model="SetId"></asp:DropDownList>
```

The rendered html is :

```
<select id="cpContent_ddlSet" ng-model="SetId">
<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
<option value="3">Test3</option>
</select>
```

The option Test3 should be selected by default when the page loads, but this isn't happening. I would have set `$scope.SetId=3`, but don't know this value before hand.

I see similar questions here but the dropdownlists are data bound the angular way, where you can easily set the selected item from $scope.

How to tackle this.

Comment: Mixing them is not good. Doing a quick search on selecteditem for dropdownlist shows different way of setting (selecting) an item in a DropDownList. My suggestion, set the selected item in Page_Load. For example: {list}.SelectedValue = theValue.ToString().

Answer (score 2):

Either you build a server side **ASP** application or you build a client side **Angular** application, but don't mix the 2 technologies.

Let Angular do the whole frontend logic and rendering and the ASP will just provide the REST services.

See [Angulars Selec](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)t for an example how to preselect a dropdown value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in this way.

I suggest to add option at first place with such as:

```
<option value="" disabled ng-selected> Make your choice:
```